# Text is supposed to be displayed when childCount equals 0, but it doesn't

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

this should be a very simple answer. I'm following a Unity with C# tutorial for making a simple Space Invaders game, and at one point it is shown that when our enemyHolder object has no child objects left (when all enemies are destroyed) the attached text under the winText function should be displayed.

So we have

```
if (enemyHolder.childCount == 0)
   {
     winText.enabled = true;
   }
```

When I run the code the text isn't displayed after the enemies are destroyed and no child object is left. It's like the code stops getting read at that point, although the character is still movable and you can generate new shots.

If I create two "Enemy" child objects and tell it to display the winText rather when the childCount reaches 1, it does work.

So why is it not working when the function calls for == 0?

**EDIT:** Complete class code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform enemyHolder;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject shot;
    public Text winText;
    public float fireRate = 0.997f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        winText.enabled = false;
        InvokeRepeating("MoveEnemy", 0.1f, 0.3f);
        enemyHolder = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    void MoveEnemy()
    {
        enemyHolder.position += Vector3.right * speed;
        foreach (Transform enemy in enemyHolder)
        {
            if (enemy.position.x < -10.5 || enemy.position.x > 10.5)
            {
                speed = -speed;
                enemyHolder.position += Vector3.down * 0.5f;
                return;
            }


            if (enemy.position.y <= -4)
            {
                GameOver.isPlayerDead = true;
                Time.timeScale = 0;
            }

            if (enemyHolder.childCount == 1)
            {
                CancelInvoke();
                InvokeRepeating("MoveEnemy", 0.1f, 0.25f);
            }
            if (enemyHolder.childCount == 0)
            {
                winText.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this code reside? Inside a coroutine? Is it run during update? Please try to post a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Oguz Ozgul I'm sorry, I'm not proficient enough at this to answer your questions. Will posting the entire code in the EnemyController class help?

Comment: Don't worry, it is ok. Yes, it will. Post the full class :) When you ask a question, others who are eager to help can be frustrated when they see just a block of code which is not sufficient for them to be of help, that's all.

Comment: ok, enemyholder is holding a transform which is already available to you you dont need that as an extra variable , enemyholder is not an array or list, so a foreach doesnt make any sense

Comment: @BugFinder I don't really know what the foreach function does, it's simply how he did that in the tutorial and it seems to work fine when he plays that through. As I said, if I duplicated the enemy object in Unity, and then told the code to display the win text when there is only 1 enemy left it works. So for some reason it doesn't execute that part when it goes from 1 to 0.

Comment: if I gave you something to hold but didnt tell you what it was and you didnt know.l how do you know its not a handgrenade? following tutorials is not a bad thing, following them without researching what they did and what it means is.

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah, he didn't explain everything written throughout.

Comment: a foreach runs through every element of the object after the ```in``` keyboard. Each of these elements will, one by one, be called whatever is after ```foreach```. Since you're not using ```enemy``` in that if, it can be just taken out - but this is only general. In your exact case, the if needs to be placed either in an update function, or just not in ```MoveEnemy```

Comment: it depends how he intended the course to be, a lot of people wouldnt expect to have to explain for loops and each kind.. the joy of learning is finding things out, and seeing what other choices there are, and then you can decide what is right or wrong - the script youve shown is not a very well designed script - if you're copying it from a tutorial, I do hope they change and improve it soon

Comment: @BugFinder Well, I think it's a beginner tutorial. I learned some Java years ago, so there should be similarities, but I don't remember too much. The code itself is not well designed in what way?

Comment: As eric pointed out, the script failed in what you want because once the thing is destroyed because its dead it cant tell you theres 0 left, because its gone.  its half coded like its expected to manage a range of enemies, and half coded like its just the one.. normally there is segregation between UI updates and enemy code, same with movement, theres a mention of firing in there too.. these things are usually all apart so they can be reused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is inside the `void MoveEnemy()` function.

I'm assuming your script is attached to in-game enemies. Your code doesn't run because the `MoveEnemy` function no longer runs if there are no enemies.

So, you need to handle enemy movement and **scene handling** in different scripts.

The code that checks the enemy holder's number of children should be placed inside a `void Update()` function. This `Update()` function should be placed on an object that never gets deleted. Its advantage is that it runs every frame.

As a convention, devs generally use separate empty objects or even the camera to attach scripts which contain Update functions that handle the scene. Good luck!

Read more on [Update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)

Comment: Oops, you're right! In the tutorial the position of the lines didn't look too clear, but the if functions checking the number of enemy children are outside the MoveEnemy closing bracket. The class code is attached to the EnemyHolder object, so if I'm fixing the brackets it works fine (the EnemyHolder doesn't get deleted). Thanks!

Comment: As I said, your script is probably attached to enemies. The easiest way to think of it is that a function can't be called on something that no longer exists, therefore it not being called when the number of children is 0. :)

Comment: A correction: these if functions are outside the "foreach" bracket, but inside the "MoveEnemy" bracket. Putting it outside "MoveEnemy" breaks the code. I assume "foreach" continuously checks for transform information of the enemy object, and when all enemies are destroyed this stops all code inside the foreach being run?

Comment: And the script itself is attached to the holding object, which still exists. It simply that part of the code which looks for information from the child objects (so I understand).

Comment: I can see your ```if```s inside the ```foreach```. Put them outside, in a ```void Update()```.

Comment: I meant in the fixed code I simply had to move them outside of the foreach. It seems to work fine under "MoveEnemy", although I suppose it would work under "void update()" too, the question is whether that is preferable?

Comment: Very well, I forgot you said the script is not attached to any enemy, that's why it works. It's preferable to keep them in ```MoveEnemy```, don't worry. Since it's called every frame, the Update function is very resource-consuming.

Comment: Can you also explain the "CancelInvoke" and "InvokeRepeating" part? I understand "InvokeRepeating" starts that "MoveEnemy" code again, but I don't write "CancelInvoke" before invoking it again, what would happen?